# "at" or "in" the same visit?

Tags: word-choice

I have been just informed that I have passed the second phase of a job interview. They asked me to visit them for the next phase at the company abroad. I'm trying to politely ask them to pack everything for this visit, so I won't be have to repeat this long distance travel again. I wrote:
"because of the long distance, I would be grateful if we could talk all issues (you concern) at(in?) the same visit." 
can we use visit in this way? or should it be replaced by: 1. date (seems less polite like I have the major authority!! which I actually don't.) 2. meeting ( I'm not sure if this visit will include just one meeting!) 3. visit date?

I really appreciate if anyone could help me. I have to answer them as soon as possible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend:

*Because of the long distance, I would be grateful if we could discuss any concerns in/during this meeting/visit.*

---

People might say "*in* this meeting" or "*during* this meeting", because "in" and "during" mean *when we are actively engaged in a meeting*.

But "*at* this meeting" makes less sense, because "at" just implies that you are at the location of the meeting.

---

*Visit* or *meeting* is preferred over *date* because while date does work in this context to mean "at this specified time", it has also has a romantic connotation.

Comment: But if you're phrasing it as a *question*, then (perhaps illogically) *at* would be the most common word choice. *Can we talk about all of the issues* ***at*** *this meeting?*

Comment: thank you for your answer! So I wasn't far from the correct form. Googling made me think using the word "visit" was completely wrong because it was used only for vaccination and medical issues. But results for "date"-as you have mentioned- were related to a romantic relationship.